# JEST - How to manage different test file with an utilities in the same __test__ folder

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have installed Jest in my react project. This is the scaffolding of one component:

```
ComponentFolder
  __test__
    unit.spec.js
    snapshot.spec.js
    utils.js
  index.js
```

At the beginning I had have just one file of test (unit) and the utils and everything worked fine but when I have added the second spec file (snapshot), jest is returned me an error:

> Your test suite must contain at least one test.

So I guess I should remove the utils file form the *test* folder but like this I will lose the structure, because that utils file is used just for tests in order to create the component with different status.

Comment: Did you find anything by any chance?

Comment: Yes, read the answer below :)

Comment: ah, I was looking for a way to have an util file inside the \_\_tests\_\_ folder that actually doesn't have `it` nor `test` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing what's in the files, but I'm guessing your newly added `snapshot.spec.js` doesn't have an `it` block, the `it` block is improperly formatted, or it doesn't contain an assertion like `expect(func()).toMatchSnapshot()`.